# Generate a simple list of dates with datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a list `L` of dates from `'2020-01-22'` to `'2020-01-25'` (very small example...). So I expect to get:

```
print(L)
['2020-01-22', '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-25']
```

I used (because I thought it was enough):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
L = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-22',end='2020-01-25').tolist()
```

But this gives me:

```
[Timestamp('2020-01-22 00:00:00', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-23 00:00:00', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-24 00:00:00', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-25 00:00:00', freq='D')]
```

I really have a problem understanding how `datetime` works; should I import something else? What would be a proper simple coding to have in my list just the dates `'2020-01-22'`, etc. in that precise format?

Comment: `list(pd.date_range(start='2020-01-22',end='2020-01-25').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need converting to strings by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
L = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-22',end='2020-01-25').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
print (L)
['2020-01-22', '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-25']
```

Here also working converting to strings (I think because 00:00:00 times):

```
L = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-22',end='2020-01-25').astype(str).tolist()
print (L)
['2020-01-22', '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-25']
```

Comment: Great thanks to you, python specialists ! So simple, but I could have spent hours on it...